# Data doesn't get saved in database, which it did before, but after I updated the database version it doesn't

Tags: java, android, database

Thanks for helping me fix my problem!

**Issue**
The issue is that the data never gets saved into the database, which it did before, but then i updated the database version and now it does not.

**Is there an error thrown?** Yes there is and its right down below.

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "0": syntax error
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting 0=20 id=csdfergeg userid=csdfergeg email=erregegergr
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Info(0,id,userid,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.vikkivuk.mxelevator.Database.addUserInfo(Database.java:50)
        at com.vikkivuk.mxelevator.finishScene$1.onClick(finishScene.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My code:

```
Database Class:

    package com.vikkivuk.mxelevator;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfo";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Info";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USERID + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + Integer.parseInt(KEY_CODE) + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUserInfo(UserInfo info){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_ID, info.UserId);
        contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, info.Email);
        contentValues.put(KEY_USERID, info.UserId);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CODE, info.CODE);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<UserInfo> getUserInfo(){
        List<UserInfo> results = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

        String GET_ALL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_ALL, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
                results.add(userInfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();
        return results;
    }

    public void deleteUserInfo(UserInfo info){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(info.ID)});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

UserInfo:

```
 package com.vikkivuk.mxelevator;

public class UserInfo {

    public String ID;
    public String UserId;
    public String Email;
    public String CODE;

    public UserInfo(String uid, String mail, String el_code){
        UserId = uid;
        Email = mail;
        CODE = el_code;
    }

    public UserInfo(String userId, String uid, String mail, String el_code){
        UserId = uid;
        Email = mail;
        ID = userId;
        CODE = el_code;
    }


}
```

UserInfoAdapter:

```
package com.vikkivuk.mxelevator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class UserInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserInfo> {

    public UserInfoAdapter(Context context, List<UserInfo> info) {
        super(context, 0, info);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        UserInfo info = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_info_item_row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView uid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_userid);
        TextView email = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_email);
        TextView textcode = convertView.findViewById(R.id.codetext);

        uid.setText(info.UserId);
        email.setText(info.Email);
        textcode.setText(info.CODE);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Finish scene:

```
package com.vikkivuk.mxelevator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.Random;

public class finishScene extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userId, email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish_scene);

        userId = findViewById(R.id.userid);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);

        CheckBox agreeCheck = findViewById(R.id.agreeCheck1);
        Boolean checked = agreeCheck.isChecked();

        Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (userId.length() < 5) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your UID is too short!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else if (email.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your EMAIL is too short!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else if (!agreeCheck.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check the agree box!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int int_random1 = rand.nextInt(10000);
                    int int_random2 = rand.nextInt(10);
                    int int_random3 = rand.nextInt(10);
                    int int_random4 = rand.nextInt(15);
                    int int_random5 = rand.nextInt(25);
                    int random_code = int_random1 + int_random2 + int_random3 + int_random4 + int_random5;

                    Database db = new Database(finishScene.this);
                    UserInfo info = new UserInfo(userId.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(random_code));
                    db.addUserInfo(info);
                    db.close();
                    userId.setText("");
                    email.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved! Pending approval...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(userId.getContext(), Success.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

ShowData:

```
   package com.vikkivuk.mxelevator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class ShowData extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_data);

        List<UserInfo> info = new Database(this).getUserInfo();
        UserInfoAdapter adapter = new UserInfoAdapter(this, info);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.userInfoList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button goback = findViewById(R.id.goback1);
        goback.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(goback.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

That's all of my classes. Also, I would like to specify that I don't actually know what database versions are since I started with the android studio 3 days ago.

Comment: What is `KEY_CODE`? Why does your table have a column labelled `0`; can you give it a meaningful name?

Comment: KEY_CODE is a randomly generated code which the user will need to enter in order to access a part of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this I implemented some change on the UserInfo class
the Id must be an **integer** and you add a **String**

database.java

```
public class MyBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfo";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Info";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";

    public MyBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USERID + " INTEGER," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUserInfo(UserInfo info) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        // contentValues.put(KEY_ID, info.UserId); i removed this 
        contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, info.Email);
        contentValues.put(KEY_USERID, info.UserId);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CODE, info.CODE);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        db.close();
    }

    public List<UserInfo> getUserInfo() {
        List<UserInfo> results = new ArrayList<>();

        String GET_ALL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_ALL, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3));
                results.add(userInfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();
        return results;
    }

    public void deleteUserInfo(UserInfo info) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(info.ID)});
        db.close();
    }

}
```

and **UserInfo** :

```
 public class UserInfo {

        public int ID;
        public int UserId;
        public String Email;
        public int CODE;

        public UserInfo(int uid, String mail, int el_code) {
            UserId = uid;
            Email = mail;
            CODE = el_code;
        }

        public UserInfo(int userId, int uid, String mail, int el_code) {
            UserId = uid;
            Email = mail;
            ID = userId;
            CODE = el_code;
        }


    }
```

i hope that's help you

Comment: So you mean i should change the integer to string or?

Comment: I changed it to: String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USERID + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT" + ")";

Comment: no create a column like String Code_Key ="Code"; and change  it for all your code

Comment: I did do that. But it doesnt work it throws the same error.

Comment: also when you use .......+ KEY_CODE + " TEXT" + ")" it's still an integer check your variabe KEY_CODE;

Comment: I said i changed the variable to a string, and it doesn't work

Comment: you need to change this `contentValues.put(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(KEY_CODE)), info.CODE);`

Comment: contentValues.put(KEY_CODE, info.CODE);

Comment: you can update your code in your question please ?

Comment: replace this :`Integer.parseInt(KEY_CODE)` by KEY_CODE i will udpate my answer

Comment: i did still no change.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: the easiest way is uninstall the app and install it

Comment: Okay, i will try

Comment: Now it gives me this error: For input string: "4672672652"

Comment: please try this ? `base.addUserInfo(new UserInfo(800,20,"em",20) ) ;`

Comment: My line is: UserInfo info = new UserInfo(Integer.parseInt(userId.getText().toString()), email.getText().toString(), random_code);

Comment: try this new `UserInfo(Integer.parseInt(userId.getText().toString()),0, email.getText().toString(), random_code);`

Comment: It saves the data now! But it crashes when I go to the show data: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: use String.ValueOf(); when you add and integer to textView

Comment: I will accept your answer since you did fix the issue I asked for!

Comment: you can explain to me why it crashes please

Comment: Oh, new issue: UNIQUE constraint failed: Info.id (code 1555) when I try and save the data

Comment: E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting id=0 code=2466 userid=0 email=gvbtrntynyjyt
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: Info.id (code 1555)

Comment: Hey, im going to go to sleep its 1 am for me. I will check your answer tommorow.

Comment: ok good night i will try to find a solution

Comment: i fixed this problem it was the unique id and you have
add the userId to the ID that's why it will fail when you add the same userId. Please review my answer I updated it, I deleted the line where you add the userId to the Unique ID in your table because the ID is automatically incremented when you add a new user

Comment: me too im going to sleep xd

Comment: BTW userId is a variable that does not have anything to do with ID , UserId is something used in my other application.

Comment: That's why I deleted this line `contentValues.put(KEY_ID, info.UserId);`

Comment: Everything works fine now! Thank you so much!